# Secure web requests via Tornado with .htaccess

Tags: python, .htaccess, authorization, tornado

I have implemented a very small application with Tornado, where HTTP GET Requests are used to perform actions. Now I would like to secure these requests. What would be a preferable way? Using .htaccess? How can I realize that?

It doesn't have to be for certain requests, it should be for all requests running on a certain port.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `secure`? You can configure Apache2 to do things like this, but your app written in tornado should be the one looking up permissions

Comment: @JonClements Looking up permissions? What do you mean, should I simply send let's say login name and password with a HTTPS?

Comment: Normally you let the app that's being used check authorisation - however, I'm now thinking you just mean authentication... there's a distinct difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you based your application on the Tornado "Hello World" example then you probably haven't, but you really should consider writing your application as a `WSGI` application. Tornado has no problem with that, and the advantage is that your application now will run under a multitude of other environments (`Apache` + `mod_wsgi` to name but one).

But how does that solve your original problem? Well, just Google "WSGI authentication middleware", it'll yield plenty of hits. Basically, what that entails is transparently 'wrapping' your `WSGI`-application in another, one allowing you to completely decouple that aspect of your application. If you're lucky, and one of hits turns out to be a perfect fit, you might get away with not witing any extra code at all.

Since you mentioned `.htaccess`: it *is* possible to have Apache do the authentication in an Apache/mod_wsgi configuration.

Comment: If you are using Tornado, then, there is no point of using Apache as a server with the blocking mod_wsgi wrapper, you should go for Nginx which plays well in terms of concurrency. Otherwise, you are not utilizing the real power of Tornado's concurrency and non-blocking features.

Answer (score 1):

`.htaccess` files are not supported by Tornado as far as I know.  Look into setting up basic authentication on Tornado.  Something like this: https://gist.github.com/660185 is probably what you want.  You'll need to store your own user credentials however as Tornado has no baked in support for that as apache does with .htaccess files.